# How to Know if Mac NIC is Dead or Dying

Tags: macos, wifi, ping

We have a home network which previously was perfect.  We moved about six months ago, and our new place is a much larger Victorian house, with thick stone walls, and one of our Macs is having major issues.

The router/modem is at one corner of the house on the ground floor (and unfortunately, can't be moved as there is an ESXi host, a switch, and a CCTV system that depend on it) - or the first floor, if you're American - and the Mac is in the study on the first floor (second floor etc etc etc).

We got ourselves a couple of Netgear extenders, and rather than connecting each of them to the 'central' modem/router, we connected the one closest to that, and then each one further out, we connected that to the extender next in line.

Sometimes, we get..

```
mac.invalid.com ➜  ~  %{ping -c 15 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=11.208 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=22.945 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=15.135 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=17.999 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=11.019 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=14.088 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=117 time=24.509 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=117 time=14.423 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=117 time=76.470 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=117 time=30.820 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=11 ttl=117 time=60.230 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=117 time=16.564 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=117 time=23.046 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=117 time=22.266 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 14 packets received, 6.7% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.019/25.766/76.470/18.450 ms
```

And sometimes, it's ..

```
mac.invalid.com  ➜  ~  %{ping -c 15 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=117 time=1640.033 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=1497.046 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=2226.044 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=1224.378 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=2220.866 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=2619.425 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=117 time=2343.340 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=117 time=3246.439 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=117 time=3491.467 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=117 time=2709.148 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=117 time=3112.649 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=117 time=3733.902 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
15 packets transmitted, 12 packets received, 20.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1224.378/2505.395/3733.902/766.261 ms
```

And sometimes, it can't even get a single pingback.

There should be no problems connecting to the Netgear extender in question, as it's about eight feet from where I'm sitting, and on the other side of a plasterboard wall.

It's perhaps worth mentioning that every single other device that sits in this room, has no problem connecting to the Internet via the same extender.

Is the Mac ready to go to the workshop, or the trash?  It's a late 2012 Mac Mini.

EDIT:  I tried pinging my gateway.  The following timeouts occurred at exactly the same time as the timeouts for the ping to Google's DNS box.

```
mac.invalid.com ➜  ~  %{ping 192.168.1.1 
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=19.014 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=19.127 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.680 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=19.635 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=21.600 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=3.036 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=27.741 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=28.008 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=9.257 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=24.714 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=13.685 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=6.382 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=40.792 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=9.818 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 16
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=19.506 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=9.401 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=9.042 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=12.356 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=12.392 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=14.834 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
23 packets transmitted, 20 packets received, 13.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.036/16.201/40.792/9.134 ms
```

EDIT 2: I flushed the routing table, just in case I had broken that by fiddling with it about a year ago!

Comment: You’re on WiFi - right?

Comment: Have you considered using wired connections?
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008F537KC/ref=dp_cerb_2
is a device I've used to allow a wired connection in any room.  I don't recommend this model because it requires reset too often, but there are many competitors.  I wired our modem to one of them, and plugged in my router/WiFi to another at the opposite corner of the house.

Answer (score 1):

The test for this is pretty easy.

Test ping to addresses on your local subnet. Faulty hardware will fail locally as well as remotely.

Routing failures will only affect pings off the subnet.

I set up two things when this happens:

1. ping your gateway
2. Set up a point to point connection and ping another device.

Failing hardware is very rare, but once you see it you can certainly catch it with the right mousetrap.